# How can I connect two design units in modelsim simulation

Tags: testing, hdl, modelsim

I am trying to simulate two design units in modelsim without a common testbench. The two design units are a processor and an I/O device. I have written the processor and the I/O device is an IP core from Altera.

I need to verify that their interfaces match. I want to leave out a common testbench because it is much faster to write a small and simple testbench in tcl(do).

I found out that modelsim can simulate two design units at the same time, by starting the simulation with:

```
vsim -i work.myProcessor work.AlteraIODevice
```

Can anyone tell me how I can connect two signal such that a signal from one entity drives the signal of the other entity? I think this is a very quick and powerful way of doing very basic testing.

I imagine that connecting two signal would be something like this:

```
force -drive /myProcessor/signalX /AlteraIODevice/signalY
```

But I have not been able to find any documentation on this matter.
I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Writing/generating a testbench fast can be done with the better editors like Emacs, Sigasi, ...

Comment: Yes if I need to make a testbench that generates stimuli and checks the values of signals this would also be my approach. But for the time being my processor contains a small program that it will execute when it is reset and clocked. What I need is an extremely simple and small test.

Comment: Are there stil noone that can help me with my problem. I have revisited the modelsim documentation and cannot find the answer to my question.

Answer (score 0):

While `force` command can be used to drive signals, the `examine` command can be used to read. Ultimately, you'll need a Tcl script to connect both ends.

Maybe for a sanity check would be OK, but since Tcl is very slow for this purpose, I don't see much gain.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Besides `force` and `examine` in a tcl script I figured that I also need `when`. But I have not been able to write such a tcl script, do you know the syntax that I need to use?